# Do my Pokemon lose levels they gained if they faint in the same battle?

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation

If I am in a battle against a trainer with multiple Pokemon, and I beat one of them, and my Pokemon gains a level or two, but against the next Pokemon, it faints, will I lose the levels that my Pokemon gained?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope. Once a pokemon has been assigned experience, fainting won't take it away from them.

In the extreme case, you can have a pokemon level up to an evolution trigger, *then* faint, *then* finish the battle, and they will evolve, despite being KO'd.

Comment: I'm fairly certain a fainted pokemon can evolve, but nothing will evolve if you lose the battle completely.

Answer (score 1):

No. Pokemon always keep levels that they've gained unless you fail to save the game when shutting off, which I've done in frustration more times than I care to remember.